# Pass Quoted/Substituted/Lazy Variables to dplyr Functions

Tags: r, dplyr

Right now I'm trying to encapsulate certain dplyr actions into their own functions. The problem that I'm running into is that I'm unsure of how to pass symbols around so that they evaluate at the right moment.

Consider the following contrived example, where I'm trying to find the top n items sorted in descending order form this data:

```
data = tibble(n = seq(10), unif = runif(10), norm = rnorm(10))
```

With dplyr, I could write the following to find the top 3:

```
data %>% top_n(3, unif) %>% arrange(desc(unif))
```

Now say I want to encapsulate this into a function. Naively, one might attempt the follow, which will fail since the value of `col` will be passed onwards:

```
top_n_sorted = function(tbl, n, col) {
  # How do I pass col as its name here?
  return(
    tbl %>%
      top_n(n, col) %>%
      arrange(desc(col))
  )
}
data %>% top_n(3, unif) %>% arrange(desc(unif))
# => KABOOM: object 'unif' not found.
```

I assumed that perhaps passing the quoted value (via substitute or quote) would do the trick, but its apparently never unwrapped by the dplyr function:

```
top_n_sorted = function(tbl, n, col) {
  return(
    tbl %>%
      top_n(n, quote(col)) %>%
      arrange(desc(quote(col)))
  )
}
data %>% top_n(3, unif) %>% arrange(desc(unif))
# => KABOOM: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable.
```

I've dug into Hadley's [article on metaprogramming](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html), and while I understand how to use quote, substitute, and eval in the context of my own functions, I'm unsure how to pass symbols onwards to other functions that make use of similar tricks like those in dplyr.

Comment: You can go around this by changing the name within the function and then changing it back to the original name.

Answer (score 1):

With the current version of **dplyr** we'd use the quosures from **rlang**:

```
library(rlang)

top_n_sorted = function(tbl, n, col) {
  col <- enquo(col)
  return(
    tbl %>%
      top_n(n, !!col) %>%
      arrange(desc(!!col))
  )
}

top_n_sorted(data,3,norm)
```

You can read more about this new-ish system [here](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good and simpler, but in general you can make whatever expression you want by creating a string and using `eval(parse(text=...))` to evaluate it. This could be handy if problems do become a bit more complex and you need something sooner rather than later.

Below I just paste together col into the spots we want and it spits out its actual value and evaluates it. This does require me entering it in quotations though rather than as a symbol.

```
top_n_sorted = function(tbl, n, col) {
  return(
         eval(
              parse(
                    text = paste0('tbl %>% top_n(n, "', col, '") %>% arrange(desc(', col, '))')
                    )
             )
        )
}

data %>% top_n_sorted(3, "unif")
```

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, I don't really get the non-standard evaluation in `dplyr` very well either, especially when you want to know how to pass inputs. However, in most cases when unquoting seems to break things, I find that just providing variable names as strings works. Usually I find that so long as you know it's a string until you give it to a `dplyr` function that can accept variable names *or* names as strings, things won't go wrong.

Here is an example that works with your first function, for example. Only difference is providing the argument `col` as `"unif"` instead of `unif`. This doesn't always work, but you don't have a situation that can't use this workaround.

```
top_n_sorted = function(tbl, n, col) {
  tbl %>%
    top_n(n, col)) %>%
    arrange(desc(col))
}

top_n_sorted(data, 3, "unif")
```